# In SQL Query - How to get Most recent records in custom query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please let me know, I have written a query to handle below conditions, can you please let me know If its anything wrong with this, I am not getting latest records based on Entry Date.

If a Entry date after the return date, please include the Entry date.
If there has not been a Entry Date, please leave blank.
If there are multiple Entry Date select last entry date.

**Current Output is**

```
MultiplePayments    AccountId   PolicyNumber    PaymentDate ReversalDate
1                    92         789         2018-05-18      2018-05-17
```

Based on the tables records latest entry date is - this is correct answer

```
MultiplePayments    AccountId   PolicyNumber    PaymentDate ReversalDate
1                    92         789         2020-06-21      2020-06-20

    drop table if exists #tempPolicyDetails;
create table #tempPolicyDetails
 (
    PolicyNumber nvarchar(10)   
 )
 --Main temp table - It will hold 10k Polices at a time
INSERT INTO #tempPolicyDetails (PolicyNumber) VALUES
('123'),
('456'),
('789')

--DROP Table if exists @tempPolicyReturnDetails;
DECLARE @tempPolicyReturnDetails TABLE (AccountId BIGINT,PolicyNumber NVARCHAR(10), ReversalDate DateTime,EntryDate DateTime)

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT Top 1 1 FROM #tempPolicyDetails) -- It loops for 5K/10K Polices
BEGIN
   DECLARE @PolicyNumber NVARCHAR(10)
   DECLARE @AccountId BIGINT =0
   
   SELECT TOP 1 @PolicyNumber = PolicyNumber FROM #tempPolicyDetails
   SELECT @AccountId =AccountId FROM PolicyInfo where AccountReference = @PolicyNumber

   -- This gives all Policy Return (Check or Card) Details
   
    INSERT INTO @tempPolicyReturnDetails (AccountId,PolicyNumber,EntryDate,ReversalDate)
    SELECT a.InitialAllocationAccountId,@PolicyNumber,a.EntryDate,b.ReversalDate
    from PaymentInfo a JOIN PaymentReversalInfo b ON a.PaymentId = b.PaymentId  
    where AccountId IN (@AccountId) 
    ORDER by a.EntryDate DESC
             
 DELETE FROM #tempPolicyDetails WHERE PolicyNumber = @PolicyNumber
    
END

-- This Gives Result of Payment date is more than Return Date and If multiple payments then it gives latest Payment Date
    SELECT
    Result.MultiplePayments,Result.AccountId,Result.PolicyNumber,
    CASE  --  If there has not been a payment, please leave blank.
        WHEN Result.EntryDate = ''
          THEN ''
        ELSE Result.EntryDate
          END AS PaymentDate,
    Result.ReversalDate
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AccountId ORDER BY a.EntryDate DESC) AS MultiplePayments,
         a.AccountId,a.PolicyNumber,a.EntryDate,a.ReversalDate
        FROM @tempPolicyReturnDetails a
        WHERE a.EntryDate > a.ReversalDate --Payment date is more than Return Date
   
    ) Result
    WHERE
    MultiplePayments = 1
    ORDER BY Result.EntryDate DESC
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are really using would all improve the question.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work, because your question is rather unclear as mentione by Gordon, but that `while` loop looks completely unnecessary, and I think the temp table is also. This whole thing could be one query